# CMDB $(...).tabs is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, otrs

I just installed OTRS and adding pakages of KIX4OTRS and I got a weird bug when zooming on a ConfigItem in our CMDB.

> `$(...).tabs` is not a function

Anyone else had this issue or can give me an hand to fix it? Im really green with OTRS :)

Comment: Looks like a jquery issue. `$()` most likely is the jquery function, and `.tabs()` is supposed to be a function as well, but it's not. Maybe a jquery plugin is not loaded or your custom jquery doesn't include the plugin you need.

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually takes place when application is not able to find relative paths to javascript files:

```
javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
```

Change them to absolute paths

```
/javascript/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
```

because its having linking with **mod_rewrite module**